# 99 f150 heater problems

Tags: ford, f-150, heater-control

I just replaced heater core on my 99 f150 and now no controls are working. I think it's a vacuum problem but not sure where to look. Dash is not completely back together but enough to check it out. I hope i don't have to drop dash again.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I'm sorry to say but I do not fully understand what your question is.  Do you mind making an [edit] to clarify?

Comment: When you say controls, which ones do you mean? The amount of heat? The selector for directing the heat to defrost, floor, panel, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I would first check you are getting vacuum and then make sure the pipes are in the correct places.